# Howto parse DWORD and LPBYTE to std::string

Tags: c++, string, active-directory

I'm writing some code which will read from Active Directory using LDAP in C++.
One of the structs I get is the `AD_OCTET_STRING`, a string represented by bytes with 8 bits.

The struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct __MIDL___MIDL_itf_ads_0000_0000_0002
{
    DWORD dwLength;
    LPBYTE lpValue;
    ADS_OCTET_STRING;
}
```

The `dwLength` is the length of the second value, which is a BYTE-pointer.
Now I need to use the length in `dwLength` to correctly parse this.

I know `basic_string` has a constructor where you can pass the length, but I did not manage to get this working.
Anyone who knows how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std::string can be initialised with any pair of iterators whose value_type is convertible to the string's character type.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>

using LPBYTE = std::uint8_t *;
using DWORD = std::uint32_t;

struct temp
{
    DWORD dwLength;
    LPBYTE lpValue;
};

std::string to_string(const temp& source)
{
  return std::string(source.lpValue, source.lpValue + source.dwLength);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx), `LPBYTE` is simply a `BYTE*`:

> This type is declared in WinDef.h as follows:
>
> `typedef BYTE far *LPBYTE;`

Now, the `BYTE` itself is simply an unsigned char pointer:

> This type is declared in WinDef.h as follows:
>
> `typedef unsigned char BYTE;`

So `LPBYTE` is actually an `unsigned char *`. However, `std::string` doesn't have a constructor that accepts `unsigned char*`, so you will need to cast it to `char *`. Knowing all that, you can finally construct an `std::string` with

```
string(reinterpret_cast<char const *>(your_struct.lpValue), your_struct.dwLength);
```